# Connected representant of a framed cobordism class (reference needed)

Tags: differential-topology, cobordism, surgery-theory

Let $N^n\subseteq M^m$ be a submanifold with a framing of the normal bundle, $2n<m$. Then $N^n$ is framed cobordant (in $M^m$) to something connected.

I believe it could be proved by directly constructing the ambient framed cobordism (using some tubular neighborhoods and surgery..) but is there not a reference for the claim?

EDIT: $n>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim doesn't seem to be true when $n=0$ and $M^m$ is orientable.

In that case framed cobordism classes correspond to homotopy classes of maps $f:M^m\to S^m$, which by the Hopf degree theorem are classified by their degree. Any map with $|\operatorname{deg}(f)|>1$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question; I'm mainly interested in the $n>0$ case.

Comment: Ah, OK. Where does your proposed proof for $n>0$ break down when $n=0$?

Comment: $(n>1)$-manifolds can be surgered to make them connected (connected sum).  Not true for 0-manifolds.

Comment: Oops -- that should have been $(n\ge 1)$-manifolds.  (Too late to edit the original comment now.)